# Websphere 8.5.5 : Overriding OpenJPA version

Tags: jpa, websphere, openjpa

I have WAS8.5.5 hosting many applications and by default it comes with OpenJPA 2.2.3

I want to use OpenJPA 2.1.1, only for a SINGLE application(other applications should use OpenJPA 2.2.3) ? Is it possible ? 
Suggestions on configurations in pom.xml would be an icing on the cake....

Answer (score 0):

> Java EE applications that use JPA functions can employ third-party persistence providers other than the providers that are included with the application server. Applications can also specify an Apache OpenJPA provider that is a different version than what is included with the application server, as long as the same version of the JPA specification is supported.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tejb_jpa3rdparty.html